# Removing Glossy Effect on UITabBar

Tags: xcode, uitabbar, appearance

I know this is a common question but it's quite different in my case.

I want an image to be placed when the bar is active and I've done that successfully using these code under didFinishLoadingWithOptions method `[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-active.png"]];`

And that's what my app looks like

[image]

Now I just want to remove that glossy effect, not the blue image on the bar

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging a little bit, I found the solution for the same. You simply need to create an UIImage object with empty image.

```
    [yourTabbar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

Thats it :)